# Django menu with reverse and args

Tags: python, django

Helo
I got a menu with item

```
Menu.add_item("main", MenuItem(u"add",
                               reverse("app.applicant_views.questionary",args={'exte':'app/layout.html'}),
                               weight=40))
```

url for questionary

```
url(r'^questionary/(?P<exte>[a-zA-Z]+)/$', 'app.applicant_views.questionary', name='questionary'),
```

and erorr

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /questionary/exte/
Invalid template name in 'extends' tag: ''. Got this from the 'exte' variable.
```

It looks like it send an empty str instead of 'app/layout.html'. Any Idea?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `kwargs`, `reverse("app.applicant_views.questionary", kwargs ={'exte':'app/layout.html'})`. [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/#django.core.urlresolvers.reverse)

Comment: with kwargs reciever NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'app.applicant_views.questionary' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'exte': u'app/layout.html'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['questionary/(?P<exte>[a-zA-Z]+)/$']